# Word frequency counter for locally stored website

Tags: python, html

I have a semi-large website locally stored (ripped from the server using httrack). This particular website's directory structure has several folders/subfolders as well as a large number of html files. I would like to know if there are any tools (it really can be anything: scripts, c++/c code, etc) that would allow me to generate a single word frequency counter table across all html files.
The trick here is that I am only interested on counting actual content words (i.e., not html code, although these could be easily removed later if that is the case). 
Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you strip out the html code, use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html)

```
>>> sentence = "Hello world. How are you? Hello"
>>> counts = collections.Counter(sentence.split()) # note that this still counts punctuation. Thus, "Hello," and "Hello" are two different words
```

If you don't have a way of stripping out html, look into [lxml](http://lxml.de/) to do so

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking more in terms of an existing tool for this task rather than me having to do all the "dirty work" :) Though if there are no existing tools to address the issue, I may go ahead and try to implement one my self.

Comment: @EveraldoAguiar: That _is_ the implementation. Install `lxml` and add `from lxml import html; text = html.fromstring(doc).text_content()` and you're basically done.

Comment: If you don't want to go with `lxml`, you could try `lynx`'s dump-as-text feature

Comment: @inspectorG4dget and Lukas Graf. Thanks for the suggestions, I'll give that a try, it sounds like a good way to go about it.

Answer (score 2):

See the advanced version of Hermetic Word Frequency Counter at http://www.hermetic.ch/wfca/wfca.htm which scans multiple files and strips out HTML tags.  Not free but does a good job of counting words in HTML files.  Even does subfolders.